# Cannot load Android Emulator on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: android

When I trying run Android Emulation, i Have error message:

```
$ tools/emulator -avd Default -verbose -debug-all
emulator: found SDK root at /opt/android-sdk-linux_86
emulator: /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='target' VALUE='android-8'
emulator:    2: KEY='path' VALUE='/home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd'
emulator: /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.ini: parsing finished
emulator: root virtual device file at /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd
emulator: /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/config.ini: parsing as .ini file
emulator:    1: KEY='hw.lcd.density' VALUE='160'
emulator:    2: KEY='sdcard.size' VALUE='200M'
emulator:    3: KEY='skin.name' VALUE='HVGA'
emulator:    4: KEY='skin.path' VALUE='platforms/android-8/skins/HVGA'
emulator:    5: KEY='image.sysdir.1' VALUE='platforms/android-8/images/'
emulator: /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/config.ini: parsing finished
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/config.ini
emulator:     found image search path: platforms/android-8/images/
emulator: found a total of 1 search paths for this AVD
emulator:     no kernel-qemu in content directory
emulator: found kernel-qemu in search dir: /opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images/
emulator:     no ramdisk.img in content directory
emulator: found ramdisk.img in search dir: /opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images/
emulator:     no system.img in content directory
emulator: found system.img in search dir: /opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images/
emulator: found userdata-qemu.img in content directory
emulator:     locking user data image at /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: found cache.img in content directory
emulator:     locking cache image at /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/cache.img
emulator: found sdcard.img in content directory
emulator:     locking SD Card image at /home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: found skin 'HVGA' in directory: platforms/android-8/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin HVGA
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir platforms/android-8/skins
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CALL to F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HANGUP to F4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_HOME to HOME
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_BACK to ESCAPE
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_MENU to PAGEUP
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to Shift-F2
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_STAR to PAGEDOWN
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_POWER to F7
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_SEARCH to F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_CAMERA to Ctrl-F3
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to KEYPAD_PLUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_UP to Ctrl-F5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to KEYPAD_MINUS
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_VOLUME_DOWN to Ctrl-F6
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_NETWORK to F8
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACING to F9
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_FULLSCREEN to Alt-ENTER
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_CENTER to KEYPAD_5
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_UP to KEYPAD_8
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_LEFT to KEYPAD_4
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_RIGHT to KEYPAD_6
emulator: adding binding BUTTON_DPAD_DOWN to KEYPAD_2
emulator: adding binding TOGGLE_TRACKBALL to F6
emulator: adding binding SHOW_TRACKBALL to DELETE
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to KEYPAD_7
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_PREV to Ctrl-F11
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to KEYPAD_9
emulator: adding binding CHANGE_LAYOUT_NEXT to Ctrl-F12
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_UP to KEYPAD_MULTIPLY
emulator: adding binding ONION_ALPHA_DOWN to KEYPAD_DIVIDE
emulator: keyset loaded from: /home/jupeter/.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file 'platforms/android-8/skins/HVGA/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: IP address of your DNS(s): 192.168.1.1
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '160'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '16m'
emulator: argv[00] = "tools/emulator"
emulator: argv[01] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[02] = "/opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images//kernel-qemu"
emulator: argv[03] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[04] = "/opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[05] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[06] = "system,size=0x4e00000,initfile=/opt/android-sdk-linux_86/platforms/android-8/images//system.img"
emulator: argv[07] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[08] = "userdata,size=0x4200000,file=/home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/userdata-qemu.img"
emulator: argv[09] = "-nand"
emulator: argv[10] = "cache,size=0x4200000,file=/home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/cache.img"
emulator: argv[11] = "-hda"
emulator: argv[12] = "/home/jupeter/.android/avd/Default.avd/sdcard.img"
emulator: argv[13] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[14] = "android-kmsg"
emulator: argv[15] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[16] = "android-qemud"
emulator: argv[17] = "-append"
emulator: argv[18] = "qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.checkjni=1 android.qemud=ttyS1 android.ndns=1"
emulator: argv[19] = "-m"
emulator: argv[20] = "96"
emulator: argv[21] = "-clock"
emulator: argv[22] = "unix"
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android/emulator-0Waqxc
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now 4e1e000

emulator: qesd_audio_init: entering
emulator: could not find libesd on this system
audio: Could not init `esd' audio driver
emulator: using 'alsa' audio input backend
emulator: qesd_audio_init: entering
emulator: could not find libesd on this system
audio: Could not init `esd' audio driver
emulator: using 'alsa' audio output backend
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 230: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

The problem is on last line:

```
Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-version.c: 230: _dl_check_map_versions: Assertion `needed != ((void *)0)' failed!
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: Not very helpful, but I'm running Ubuntu 10.04 and that command you posted works fine for me...

Comment: Are you trying to run it from the command line? Run it from the AVD window in eclipse

Comment: try deleting this instance of the emulator and create a new one. I second flamarri, try using eclipse. Your life will be much easier! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where was problem ... and i find out that it's not related with android application, but my one library.

I have corrupted "/lib32/libdbus-1.so.3.4.0" file.

I figured out, when I compare md5sum from my computer and new instalation of Ubuntu on VirtualBox. I this case probably couse of the problem was with my disk.

Wrong md5sum:

```
@/lib32# md5sum libdbus-1.so.3.4.0 
a1ce67fa4e733bf94939e9a699d3a9ff  libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
```

Correct md5sum:

```
@:/lib32/# md5sum libc-2.11.1.so 
dba5fd388fe58c0865829192c0112ad1  libdbus-1.so.3.4.0
```

Comment: Hello! Any idea of how to fix it?